# SWIFT XCODE error

Tags: xcode, swift, declaration

I am a complete beginner in coding. I managed to get some working code in Playground but once I moved to building a project nothing worked.
This is for OS X.
I have used the following simple lines of code in Playground and AppDelegate contexts.  It runs and outputs to the console without error in Playground but returns an error in AppDelegate.swift - Expected declaration for the " for num in availcrop" line with a red arrow under the f in for.

```
var availcrop = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
 for num in availcrop
 {
    var ran = 1000+randInt(2000)
    availcrop[num] = ran
    println(availcrop[num])

 }
```

- the println is not planned for the project.  Just in the Playground for testing
Both have imported Cocoa.  One runs and the other crashes. In Playground the array name avail crop is blue implying it is recognised I suppose.  In the AppDelegate.swift it remains grey.

Comment: XCode often gets hick-ups in recognizing keys (not talking about crashing SourceKit Service). But you need to tell where and how your code crashes.

Comment: Did you put this code in a method or outside?  The error is probably because everything's outside of a method.  At least the for-loop needs to be inside a function or method.

Comment: Thank for the replies.  The program fails a build and flags the "for" as the beginning of the error -expected declaration.

Comment: In Playground it is outside a method and works.  In the Project it is also outside a method and does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Once you're dealing with classes and objects, code generally needs to be inside some method so that it can be invoked by name.

Try:

```
func printRandoms {
// Your code here
}
```